# How in fluentd convert field type

Tags: fluentd

In **Logstash**, the type of field can be changed using [the mutate construction](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/2.3/plugins-filters-mutate.html). 
How can this be done in **Fluentd**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User `record_transformer`.
This filter allows you to convert records with arbitrary ruby expressions.
This is included in Fluentd’s core. No installation required.

For details, refer to the following documents:
http://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/filter_record_transformer